# Get the Id/name of an element from dynamically generated HTML JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

How can I get the **id** or **name** of **`input`** element of `type="text"` from dynamically generated HTML.

I need to get the Id of   `<input name="ctl00$DefaultContent$ctl2" type="text">`

```
 <tr>
    <td class="TextBold" >1.</td>
    <td class="TextBold" >Content for Question 1:</td>
    <td class="TextBold" >
      <input name="ctl00$DefaultContent$ctl2" type="text" class="TextNormal" />
    </td>
  </tr>
```

Thank in advance

BB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Descriptiom

Your `<input name="ctl00$DefaultContent$ctl2" type="text" class="TextNormal" />` has no `id` attribute. But you can get a collection of every `input type text` using this selector `$("input[type='text'])`. I think you want to get the `name` attribute.

Check out the sample and this [jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/rhPMR/).

#### Sample

```
$(function() {
    $("input[type='text']").each(function() {
       alert("id = " + $(this).attr("id")); 
       alert("name = " + $(this).attr("name")); 
    });
});
```

#### More Information

- [jQuery - Attribute Equals Selector [name="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)
- [jQuery - all Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)
- [jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/rhPMR/)

### Update

Your `input` element has a `class` attribute. You can get all elements that has this `class` using

```
$(".TextNormal").each(function() {
    alert("id = " + $(this).attr("id")); 
    alert("name = " + $(this).attr("name")); 
});
```

Comment: Thank you dknaack. In the above example all i know is the content of the first TD which is "1.". Is there a way using "1." I can get the "name" of input[type='text']. Here is what i came up with var id = $("td:contains('15'):nth-child(2)").attr('name'); but this returns "Undefined"

Comment: You can use the `:eq()` selector to get the element at position n. 

In your case you can do `$(".TextNormal:eq(2)")` to get the third element.

Check out the "all selectors" link from my answer. Very easy to learn and every selector has a nice sample. Hope this helps!