# How to find an element which has dynamic generating id

Tags: selenium, cucumber-java

I need to click this element and upload a document, but here the id of the button is generating dynamically.

Element:

```
<button class="md-raised md-primary e-button-small md-button md-ink-ripple" type="button" ng-transclude="" aria-label="Approve" data-ng-file-select="onFileSelect($files, rule)" data-accept="*/*" multiple="multiple" onclick="document.getElementById(&quot;--ng-file-upload-0.6873237604099194&quot;).click()" id="e--ng-file-upload-0.6873237604099194" style="overflow: hidden;">
  <span class="ng-scope">Upload File</span>
  <div class="md-ripple-container" style=""></div>
</button>
```

Tried to find and click in below ways:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[id^='e--ng-file-upload']]")).click();  

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Approve')]")).click();
```

- I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25869101/what-is-the-way-to-locate-an-element-which-has-dynamic-id-even-if-xpath-css) as well.

and getting this error every time:

> org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: An
>   invalid or illegal selector was specified   (Session info:
>   chrome=60.0.3112.113)   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477700
>   (0057494ad8732195794a7b32078424f92a5fce41),platform=Windows NT
>   10.0.14393 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 104 milliseconds

Comment: Here You will get your Answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8918164/get-the-id-name-of-an-element-from-dynamically-generated-html-jquery

Comment: Hi zsbappa, I need to achieve it using selenium java, example is in Jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tried to get this item with text "Approve", but this is aria-label so you should do it like this using xpath (assuming that this is only button that have this label):

`//button[@aria-label='Approve']`

or with css selector:

`button[aria-label=Approve]`

Answer (score 1):

Your first selector has an extra ] at the end. It should be

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[id^='e--ng-file-upload']")).click();
```

Your second selector... I don't know how it's supposed to work because "Approve" isn't contained in that element. You might try

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Upload File')]")).click();
```

Other options:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[aria-label='Approve']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[.='Upload File']")).click();
```

Comment: I posted 4 different selectors, all of which are valid, so you must be getting the error from something else. You need to update your question with what you have tried (post the code for each one) and the error you received for each.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one for dynamic value

```
webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@id, 'Somevalue')]"));
```